# Debugging realtime database security rules for live app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Recently I updated security rules for my realtime database in production. Since I have updated the rules I have observed an increase in the number of denies and errors. I wanted to know which path in the database is resulting in these errors, so I can fix them. Also, I wanted to know whether some users are actually using the app in unethical ways or are the actual users facing the issue. For this, I will need to know which path in the database results in the denial. I am looking for something like the logs which show the paths of all denial and error while making a read or write to the realtime database.

I tried checking out [Cloud monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/) but that doesn't satisfy my needs. Do you know how can I solve this issue as I am not facing any issue with the rules while testing?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no logging of security rule violations.  The best you can do trap security rule rejections in your app and log them from there.  However, that will not necessarily uncover malicious use, as that that doesn't require the use of your app.  I suggest [contacting Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to file a feature request.